# Returning view model from OData web api with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to return a custom view model from an ODataController.  Here is the view model:

```
public class TaskViewModel
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TaskViewModel> Get(ODataQueryOptions<TaskViewModel> options)
{
    IEnumerable<Task> tasks = db.Tasks.AsEnumerable();
    ...
    var vm = from t in tasks
             select new TaskViewModel
             {
                 TaskID = t.TaskID,
                 Name = t.Name,
                 Details = t.Details,
                 DueDate = t.DueDate,
                 Project = t.Project
             }
    return vm.AsEnumerable();
}
```

The Task entity looks like this (generated from database-first EDMX):

```
public partial class Task
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    ... //other properties I don't want exposed
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to perform a GET, I receive the following message:

"No NavigationLink factory was found for the navigation property 'Project' from entity type 'MyApplication.ViewModels.TaskViewModel' on entity set 'Tasks'.  Try calling HasNavigationPropertyLink on the EntitySetConfiguration."

Here is my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
builder.EntitySet<Project>("Projects").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.ProjectID);
builder.EntitySet<Task>("Tasks").EntityType.HasKey(t => t.TaskID);
...
builder.EntitySet<ViewModels.TaskViewModel>("TaskViewModel");
```

I've successfully done this with another entity in the application (Project), so I don't know why this one isn't working.  The only difference is the Task entity references the Project entity.

Any help/insight is appreciated.

Comment: Are you having any table called `TaskViewModel` in your database?

Comment: No, it's not part of the database.  However, I was able to successfully use a ProjectViewModel class w/o adding it to the database.

Comment: Then why have you applied line `builder.EntitySet<ViewModels.TaskViewModel>("TaskViewModel");` to your configuration?

Comment: Everything I had read stated that had to be in there. If I take it out, I receive the error: "The given model does not contain the type 'MyApplication.ViewModels.TaskViewModel'.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008450/using-ef-and-webapi-how-can-i-return-a-viewmodel-and-support-iqueryable-odata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working.  All I did was make the TaskViewModel class a derived class of Task.

From:

```
public class TaskViewModel
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    ...
    public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

To:

```
public class TaskViewModel : Task
{
    public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

It's also worth noting that this worked with or without the entry for TaskViewModel in WebApiConfig.cs.

Comment: Having your DTO derive from your domain model is far from ideal

Comment: sorry to necro up this thread but has anyone found a more optimal solution that is just as succinct?

Comment: @Cocowalla why you said that?

Comment: @Badulake because one of the main reasons for DTOs is that views often need different data than the domain model provides, or need it in a flattened, formatted, parsed, or otherwise differing format

Comment: @Cocowalla ,sometimes could happen that you need just a few more fields that the Domain model class, how do you handle that?

Comment: @Badulake I'd still use a DTO that doesn't inherit from my domain model, and I'd use AutoMapper or similar to do the monkey-work of mapping properties to the DTO for me