# How to format iqueryable mvc 4 web api requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata, iqueryable

I'd like to use iqueryable on all my collections so that I get all of the odata features. However I need to format the response of the request with the following fields;

```
{
   href: "url to resouce",
   length: 10,
   items: [
     "(IQueryable results)"
   ]
}
```

Formatting the response isnt the hard part but keeping all of the odata "stuff" working is.

So my code looks like;

```
MyFormattedResponse.Href = "poop.com";
MyFormattedResponse.Length = 0;
MyFormattedResponse.Items = _myRepo.Gets();
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, MyFormattedResponse);
```

But the error I get is:

> The action 'Get' on controller 'MyResource' with return type
>   'MyObject' cannot support querying. Ensure the type of the returned
>   content is IEnumerable, IQueryable, or a generic form of either
>   interface.

Is this something I can construct in a media formatter or perhaps a filter?

I really want to keep the odata awesomeness...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer I've provided:

[Web API Queryable - how to apply AutoMapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484692/web-api-queryable-how-to-apply-automapper/14490362#14490362)

Your case is similar, you can do something like this:

```
public MyFormattedResponse Get(ODataQueryOptions<Person> query)
{
    var results = query.ApplyTo(_myRepo.Gets()) as IEnumerable<Person>;
    return new MyFormattedResponse() { Href = "foo.com", Length = 5, Items = results };
}
```

Make sure you remove the `[Queryable]` attribute.