# Net Core 3: Apply Automapper with OData, No overload for ProjectTo takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata, automapper

How do I apply Automapper with Odata in NetCore 3? I am receiving error below, using resource. Has the syntax been updated?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28725063/14727392

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<PersonDto> Get() {
     _dbContext.Set<Persons>().ProjectTo<PersonDto>();
}
```

> Error: No overload for ProjectTo takes 0 arguments

Currently using Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has changed to the following syntax:

```
var result = _mapper.ProjectTo<PersonDto>(_dbContext.Set<PersonDto>());
```

**Resource:**

https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2020/05/automapper-projectto-instance-version/